# How to square a zeroth order bessel function of the first kind?

Tags: calculus, power-series, bessel-functions

I've started going through Frank Bowman's book 'Introduction to Bessel Functions' and while trying to follow along there's a specific point that I'm not quite how how it's reached.

[Image of the page I'm confused about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPYT3.jpg)

For point 5 in the middle of the page, it mentions taking $\frac{1}{xJ_o^2(x)}$ where $J_o(x)$ is the zeroth order bessel function of the first kind, and replacing $J_o(x)$ with it's power series.

This then results in the following first few terms:

$\frac{1}{xJ_o^2(x)} = \frac{1}{x}$ + $\frac{x}{2}$ + $\frac{5x^3}{32}$ + ...

I'm confused as to how this result is reached, because in my attempts to expand this using the power series I am getting:

$\frac{1}{xJ_o^2(x)} = \frac{1}{x} - \frac{2}{x^3} + \frac{32}{3x^5}$ + ...

I got this by essentially 'brute forcing' it and just expanding the equation using only the first three terms of the function, like so:

$J_o(x) = 1 - \frac{x^2}{4} + \frac{x^4}{64}$

I'm not sure of a different way to go about it to get the result from the book. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start, as you did with
$$J_0(x)=1-\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{x^4}{64}+O\left(x^6\right)$$
Square it
$$J_0(x){}^2=1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{3 x^4}{32}+O\left(x^6\right)$$
$$x\,J_0(x){}^2=x-\frac{x^3}{2}+\frac{3 x^5}{32}+O\left(x^7\right)$$
Long division
$$\frac 1 {x\,J_0(x){}^2}=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{x}{2}+\frac{5 x^3}{32}+O\left(x^5\right)$$

Comment: Thanks for replying so quick! I was very silly for treating the 1/ division as just flipping all the terms. I've been giving it a go for the long division part trying to use partial fractions but best I can get out of it is the $\frac{1}{x}$ term. Would you be able to elaborate a bit more on the long division part?